# MySQL LIKE query always returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm Trying to search for usernames using LIKE query, however the query always return 0 and the usernames does exists! I'm using MYSQL terminal that with MAMP PRO server and here what i tried:

```
SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE username LIKE '٪w٪';
SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE username LIKE '٪w';
SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE username LIKE 'w٪';
SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE username LIKE '٪?٪';
```

Always the result is the same 0 what can be the problem!?

Comment: Hi,
By returning 0, do you mean no result is coming ? I don't know MAMP PRO but i think there is something wrong with your '٪' character. Can you try with the character '%' ?

Comment: yes you are right the problem is in the character, i don't know how is that possible and i'm writing the percentage character from the keyboard!

Comment: Okay then.. posting it as answer

Comment: `%` copy this character and paste it in the terminal, then see the results

Answer (score 1):

You are using percent character from Arabic encoding, copy following character and all will be fine (or switch your keyboard on English based keyboard and then type):

`%`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it returns 0 - I suspect you mean the queries return no rows. Also you did not provide any details of the records you expected the query to return.

Applying further guesswork, I think the first 2 queries are intended to return records where the username *starts* with zW - in which case you should be specify a wildcard in your literal, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE username LIKE '٪w%';
```

From [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html):

> With LIKE you can use the following two wildcard characters in the pattern:
>
> % matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
>
> _ matches exactly one character.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Walid Naceri You have wrong special character use **%w%** Like this

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.